# Is driver responsible to return buffers in the same order they were passed to it

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, v4l2

According to the requirements of the `V4L2` framework is a driver must return buffers in the same order they were passed to it? Is it allowed return buffers in another order even if frames are passed consecutively?

For instance if three buffers are previously requested via `VIDIOC_REQBUFS` and `VIDIOC_QUERYBUF` is it allowed for driver such behavior?

```
Time |  VIDIOC_QBUF   | VIDIOC_DQBUF
-----+----------------+----------------  
  |    [buf 0 emppty]
  |    [buf 1 emppty]
  |    [buf 2 emppty]
  |                    [buf 0 frame 0]
  |    [buf 0 emppty]
  |                    [buf 2 frame 1]
  |    [buf 2 emppty]
  |                    [buf 1 frame 2]
  |         ...             ...
  v
```